# How to maintain jQuery ui numeric spinner between partial postbacks

Tags: jquery, spinner

I lose the spinner feature of my textbox when the page posts back.  I am setting up this way:

$("[id$='_txtSpinner']").spinner({ max: 60, min: 0 });

but after a partial postback the arrows are gone.  I need something kind of like .live('click', function...) but I don't know the syntax to make it work for the spinner.

I know I can get it to work by duplicating in pageLoad but I'm already using pageLoad for other things elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`live` only applies to event handling.  You can check out the livequery plugin, maybe that will do what you want.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery

Or you can include a `<script>` tag in your response that makes a call to the spinner method.